# Insert data to mysql database through jsp

Tags: jsp

What is the wrong in this code, it is not getting processing, when I click the submit button it forwards to this insert.jsp and blank page appears (result is failing).

```
/*
Form.html
*/

<html>
<form method="post" action="Insert.jsp"> //form start
<table>
<tr><td>Fname:</td><td><input type="text" name="fname"></td></tr>
<tr><td>LName:</td><td><input type="text" name="lname"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Email:</td><td><input type="text" name="email"></td></tr>
<tr><td>pass:</td><td><input type="password" name="pass"></td></tr>
<tr><td>confirm pass:</td><td><input type="password" name="cpass"></td></tr>
<tr><td>dob:</td><td><input type="text" name="dob"></td></tr>
<tr><td>age:</td><td><input type="text" name="age"></td></tr>
<tr><td>gender:</td><td><input type="text" name="gender"></td></tr>
<tr><td>address:</td><td><input type="text" name="address"></td></tr>
<tr><td>country:</td><td><input type="text" name="country"></td></tr>
<tr><td>state:</td><td><input type="text" name="state"></td></tr>
<tr><td>city:</td><td><input type="text" name="city"></td></tr>
<tr><td>telephone:</td><td><input type="text" name="tno"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Mobile:</td><td><input type="text" name="mobile"></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</html>

/*
Insert.jsp 
*/
<%@page import="java.sql.*,java.util.*"%> // import
<%
String fname=request.getParameter("fname");
String lname=request.getParameter("lname");
String email=request.getParameter("email");
String pass=request.getParameter("pass");
String cpass=request.getParameter("cpass");
String dob=request.getParameter("dob");
int age=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("age"));
String gender=request.getParameter("gender");
String address=request.getParameter("address");
String country=request.getParameter("country");
String state=request.getParameter("state");
String city=request.getParameter("city");
int tno=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("tno"));
int mobile=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("mobile"));
        try{
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
           Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student", "root", "");
           Statement st=con.createStatement();
           int i=st.executeUpdate("insert into student(fname,lname,email,pass,cpass,dob,age,gender,address,country,state,city,tno,mobile) values('"+fname+"','"+lname+"','"+email+"','"+pass+"','"+cpass+"','"+dob+"','"+age+"','"+gender+"',"+address+",'"+country+"','"+state+"','"+city+"','"+city+"','"+tno+"','"+mobile+"')");
        out.println("Data is successfully inserted!");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        System.out.print(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        %>
```

Comment: You have to post the error log. The error must be printed there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your urgency isn't our problem.

It'd be more helpful if you could cite a log message or a stack trace than "blank page" and "failing".

When you hit the submit button, what do you expect to be displayed?

This is a bad design.  You ought not have database code in your JSP.  Scriptlets are a very bad idea.  Learn JSTL.  The `<sql>` tags might even be what you need.

A better idea would be a servlet between the JSP and the database that would authenticate and authorize the user, bind and validate inputs, perform the database operations on the user's behalf, marshal the response into request or session scope, and stream the response to the page that needed to be displayed.

I'm guessing that you'd like to display the state of the database after the INSERT, so there ought to be a table showing all the values.  How does your JSP know how to do that?

Comment: im new to jsp,can u show me a easy example to insert the data into the mysql database plz?

Answer (score 3):

Remove single quotes for numeric type fields inside insert statement. Also change mobile number data type as long, since int cant hold 10 digit numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Everythign is wrong with that. It is for example full of sql injection problems. also check that your database is in autocommit mode or that you begin/end a transaction.

Comment: your problem is not being new to jsp, more like being new to java and database programming in general. learn to use preparedstatement. possibly read up on hibernate or JPA. Separate database code from view code (jsp). Have you checked that it doesnt insert the stuff into database? have you checked the logs for errors? That page will not show anything even if it works correctly. You will have to write some html/jsp into it to print stuff out.

Answer (score 0):

```
@WebServlet(name = "signup", urlPatterns = {"/signup"})
public class signup extends HttpServlet {


@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String firstName = request.getParameter("firstname");
    String lastName = request.getParameter("lastname");
    String eMail = request.getParameter("email");
    String UserName = request.getParameter("username");
    String passWord = request.getParameter("password");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    if (eMail.matches("^([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.])+\\@([a-zA-Z0-9])+\\.([A-Za-z0-9]{2,4})")) {
        if (passWord.matches("^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])(?=[\\S]+$).{8,}$")) {

            UserBean u = new UserBean();
            u.setname(firstName);
            u.setlname(lastName);
            u.setemail(eMail);
            u.setusername(UserName);
            u.setpasswords(passWord);
            UserManager umg = new UserManager();

            if (umg.insertUser(u)) {
                out.print("Registered Successfully");
            } else {
                out.print("Registration Failed");
            }

        } else {
            out.print("<h4 style='color: red; margin-left: -66px;'>Invalid Password</h4>");

        }
    } else {
        out.print("<h4 style='color: red; margin-left: -66px;'>Invalid Email</h4>");
    }

}

/**
 * Returns a short description of the servlet.
 *
 * @return a String containing servlet description
 */
@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>
}
```